# Replace integer with word

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I receive numbers for the movie genres from an api. Which means, 1 = Action, 2 = Drama, 3 = Horror .... 
I want to display the genre name instead of the number.How can i do that?

```
 {{::movie.genre}}
```

movies have multiple genres so that has to works too. movie genre: 1&2

Can i use a filter like this ?

`{{::today | date}}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can make this replacement in the controller before setting data in $scope

Comment: I would create a filter to do that, so that way you can reuse it if needs be. If you share your code I can take a look and give you a dig out

Comment: can you show me an example @Alainlb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

```
.filter('genre', function() {
  return function(input) {
    input = input || '';
    var out = '';
    switch(input) {
      case 1:
        out = 'horror';
        break;
      case 2:
        out = 'comedy';
        break;
      default:
        out = input;
    }
    return out;
  };
})
```